# How to remove unnecessary information from Kafka Schema Registry?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I am currently using Kafka along Debezium to ingest some data from Mongo db. When data get ingested, the schema registry (Confluent) shows some extra unwanted info that cause to have more schema versions than expected. This is the type of "unwanted" schema:

```
...
       {
          "connect.name": "mongodbserver1.data_transformer.api_data_asset.content.text_representation",
          "fields": [
            {
              "default": null,
              "name": "language",
              "type": [
                "null",
                "string"
              ]
            },
            {
              "default": null,
              "name": "script",
              "type": [
                "null",
                "string"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "name": "text_representation",
          "namespace": "mongodbserver1.data_transformer.api_data_asset.content",
          "type": "record"
        }
      ]
    },
...
```

Is there any way to avoid that type of schema info?

Answer (score 0):

According to this, you have a text_representation Object in your database, therefore, that'll be part of your schema.

You can choose to use Connect transforms to alter the format of your record before its actually passed into the AvroConverter, which decides what gets registered to the registry, not Debezium.